# If a ring element is right-invertible, but not left-invertible, then it has infinitely many right-inverses.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, inverse, noncommutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a ring and $a\in A$ an element that has a right-inverse but does not have a left-inverse. Show that $a$ has infinitely many right-inverses.

Comment: The title should be more helpful

Comment: Please formulate this question more clearly.

Comment: Hmm, I duped it as the wrong question. I'm pretty sure this has already been asked though.

Comment: The question is almost certainly "If $a$ is left invertible but not right invertible, show $a$ has infinitely many distinct left inverses", a classic result.

Comment: So I understand this question was closed because of the unbelievable language it was "written" in? Because it is not the duplicate of Kaplansky's theorem, at least not directly.

Comment: @DonAntonio Yeah, it's not a duplicate of the question, but the question text contains Kaplansky's argument (identical to azimut's below).

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**
Let $b$ be a right-inverse of $a$. For any $i \geq 0$, we define $b_i = (1-ba)a^i + b$. Show that if $a$ doesn't have a left-inverse, the $b_i$ are pairwise distinct right-inverses of $a$.