# Show that if $a \in R$ has more than one left-inverse then it has infinite.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let R is a ring with identity $1$. Show that if $a \in R$ has more than one left-inverse then it has infinite.

Comment: The proof you are looking for is contained in the question there.

Comment: Something at [a duplicate linked to the duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/329621/29335) may also be useful.